# How to set css cursor value to variable within jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

I am trying to make a little jQuery plugin so I can dynamically change the cursor. But when I try and set the cursor to a variable it doesn't do anything.

Here's the code in the JS file:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.dynamicCursors = function () {
    this.each(function () {

        var cursorImage = null;
        $(this).css('cursor', 'url(' + cursorImage + '),auto');

        });
    });   
});
}(jQuery));
```

And here's the code for the code within the `<script>` tag in the HTML file:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
            $('body').dynamicCursors();
        });

        var cursorImage = 'generic.cur';
```

If anyone needs anymore information please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You're setting the cursorImage to null right before you set the css style. Is that intentional?

Comment: Are you testing in the opera ? it doesnt work properly in opera as far as i know

Comment: @JohnWilliamDomingo Well how else would I declare the variable?

Comment: @ZumryMohamed No. I'm testing it in Chrome.

Comment: @Njinx, see the answer I posted. I proposed two options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're setting the `cursorImage` to null before you set the style attribute. Also, you've got imbalanced parentheses.

Try passing the cursor URL as a parameter to the function:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.dynamicCursors = function (cursorImage) {
    this.each(function () {
      $(this).css('cursor', 'url(' + cursorImage + '),auto');
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

And you can call it like so:

```
$('body').dynamicCursors('generic.cur')
```

## Alternative

If you know all the cursors you're going to use, you can use classes:

```
/* CSS */
.cursor-generic {
  cursor: url('generic.cur'), auto;
}
```

So you can just:

```
$(this).addClass('cursor-generic');
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fv3Bk/1/)

```
$("div").css('cursor','url(http://w17.snunit.k12.il/images/big_arrow.png),auto');
```

it works well

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to simply pass the cursor as a parameter to the function like:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.dynamicCursors = function(cursorImage) {
    this.each(function() {
      $(this).css('cursor', 'url(' + cursorImage + '),auto');
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Then you would simply call it like:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('body').dynamicCursors('generic.cur');
});
```

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't seem to work. I checked my console and got this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: @Njinx sorry, you had some syntax errors in your function I didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

Just change "var cursorImage=null;" to "var cursorImage;".